# Error while casting in JPQL

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql

This is on a JSF + JPA web application.

When I used the following JPQL query which include casting, it gives an error difficult to understand.

This is the query

```
jpql = "select new data.dataStructure.PharmacyStockRow(amp.vmp.name, sum(s.stock), "
+ "sum(s.itemBatch.purcahseRate * s.stock), sum(s.itemBatch.retailsaleRate * s.stock))"
+ "from Stock s join treat(s.itemBatch.item as Amp)amp "
+ "where s.stock>:z and s.department=:d "
+ "group by amp.vmp ";
m.put("d", department);
m.put("z", 0.0);
```

This is the class created just to receive the result from the query.

```
package data.dataStructure;

public class PharmacyStockRow {
   String code;
   String name;
   Double qty;
   Double purchaseValue;
   Double saleValue;

   public PharmacyStockRow() {
   }

   public PharmacyStockRow(String name, Double qty, Double purchaseValue, Double saleValue) {
       this.name = name;
       this.qty = qty;
       this.purchaseValue = purchaseValue;
       this.saleValue = saleValue;
   }
```

I have a Stock class which stores data about stocks. It has a ItemBatch class which represent a batch. Batch has an Item. That item is actually a Amp, which extends Item. Amp has a Vmp. I want to get the stocks by Vmp. It would have been very easy if ItemBatch has a property of Amp, but I had to use more generic Item as the reference. So I need to cast Item to Amp within the Java Resistance Query. I tried it but it gives following error.

I use EclipseLink 2.5 as the Persistance Provider.

[image: This is the class diagram.]

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6034] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Invalid query item expression [
Query Key vmp
   Query Key item (entity.pharmacy.Amp) 
      Query Key itemBatch
         Base entity.pharmacy.Stock].
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=Stock jpql="select new data.dataStructure.PharmacyStockRow(amp.vmp.name, sum(s.stock), sum(s.itemBatch.purcahseRate * s.stock), sum(s.itemBatch.retailsaleRate * s.stock))  from Stock s join treat(s.itemBatch.item as Amp)amp where s.stock>:z and s.department=:d group by amp ")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.invalidExpressionForQueryItem(QueryException.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.getLeafDescriptorFor(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1460)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.getLeafMappingFor(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1408)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ReportItem.initialize(ReportItem.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ConstructorReportItem.initialize(ConstructorReportItem.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.prepare(ReportQuery.java:1044)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.checkPrepare(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.prepareCall(DatabaseQuery.java:1741)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1475)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1497)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the multiplication inside the `sum(...)` is valid JPQL

Comment: That I have done previously. I have changed everything separately and found that error comes when a casted variable is in group by clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to solved the issue, but did a work around. I add all the additional methods in the child class into the parent class so that the casting was not necessary.